# How can i always add a query string like lang=en to angular request

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

We are doing I18N recently, and we have a menu to switch the language between language en, jp, and fr.
Once we switch the language, the url become like below, there is a querystring append in the end of the url.

```
http://localhost:3030/loadTests?lang=en
```

Here is the question, because we don't append the lang parameter in all existing links and hrefs, if we click some link on the website, the url would be like:

```
http://localhost:3030/loadTests/1
```

the querystring lang=en didn't append in the end of the url, and we want the lang=en always append in the end of the url, how can i achieve it?

Hope i describe my question clearly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Angular JS http Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to do so.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
         $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
             return {
                 'request': function (config) {
                     config.url = config.url + '?lang=en';
                     return config;
                 }

             }
         });
     });
```

**Edit** : In order to fetch the current query string parameter from the url, you can follow this answer. --> [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Then in the code you can write like this :

```
config.url = config.url + '?lang=' + getParameterByName('lang');
```

Comment: Instead of always using en, it needs to use what is currently in the querystring.

Comment: what i need to intercept is the url in state.go(), config.url will catch all the http request url, rather than the url show in the browser.

Comment: e.g. if the browser url is:http://localhost:3030/loadTests?lang=en, the real http request in the backend like http://.../en.json, http://.../xxx.html,http://.../xxx.png these kind of request can be  capture in the config.url, but 'http://localhost:3030/loadTests?lang=en' is the ui-router state url, this cannot be captured by your interceptor, can you help on this?

Comment: Are you making these requests through Angular ?? is yes, then this interceptor will intercept those requests